# get max ids by group mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have this table called `sw_sowing`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id  |   id_unit  |  date      |  id_variety |  type  |  status |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |      1     | 2017-08-10 |     1        |  SW   |    200  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  2  |      1     | 2017-10-10 |     1        |  ER   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  3  |      1     | 2017-11-30 |     2        |  SW   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  4  |      2     | 2017-12-10 |     3        |  SW   |    200  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  5  |      2     | 2017-12-10 |     3        |  ER   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  6  |      3     | 2017-08-05 |     4        |  SW   |    200  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  7  |      3     | 2017-12-13 |     4        |  ER   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  8  |      3     | 2018-01-04 |     1        |  SW   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  9  |      3     | 2018-01-04 |     2        |  SW   |    100  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to know the current status and id_variety of the id_unit depending on a date.
I have this query:

```
SELECT sw_sowing.id_unit, sw_sowing.id_variety, sw_sowing.type, sw_sowing.status
FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id
        FROM sw_sowing
        WHERE date <= '2018-09-06'
        GROUP BY id_unit
) AS sw
INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
```

It gives me the following result:

```
----------------------------------------------------- 
   id_unit  |    id_variety |    type    |   status |
-----------------------------------------------------
      1     |        2      |     SW     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
      2     |        3      |     ER     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
      3     |        2      |     SW     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that the `id_unit = 3` has two different `id_variety` with `state = 100`, but the previous query give the last one and I want the two `id_variety`.

Something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------- 
   id_unit  |    id_variety |    type    |   status |
-----------------------------------------------------
      1     |        2      |     SW     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
      2     |        3      |     ER     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
      3     |        1      |     SW     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
      3     |        2      |     SW     |    100   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I hope that you can help me!

Comment: Then why do you search for the max ids? Search for the `state = 100` if that's you need to fetch.

Comment: @Shadow Beacuse If I need to know the state of the id_unit , for example in '2017-08-09', the result is that the `id_unit  = 1` had `type = 'SW'` AND `status = 200` AND `id_variety = 1`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not get what you are after. I think you should edit your question and explain the selection criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include id_variety on the GROUP BY.

```
    SELECT sw_sowing.id_unit, sw_sowing.id_variety, sw_sowing.type, sw_sowing.status
FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id
        FROM sw_sowing
        WHERE date <= '2018-09-06'
        GROUP BY id_unit,id_variety
) AS sw
INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I donot know why you have this requirement, but I think you can achieve this using the below query:

```
SELECT id_unit, id_variety, type, status FROM sw_sowing WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM sw_sowing WHERE (id_unit, date) IN (
    SELECT id_unit, MAX(date) FROM sw_sowing 
    WHERE date <= '2018-09-06'
    GROUP BY id_unit)
  GROUP BY id_unit, id_variety)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If downvoted, please share a comment so I can know the reason for this not solving the question.