# Performance MySQL query with for loop

Tags: php, mysql, performance, phalcon

In this method, first I have to get sundays dates between two dates, in this case about 1 year. Then I go through the dates in a for loop and set them to the query. I use `prepared statements` to make it faster.

```
//Get the first day and last day
$dateInitial = strtotime('2018-08-21');
$dateFinal   = strtotime('2019-08-21');
$final       = array();

$sql = "SELECT id_product, product, plant_sowing, plant_production, area_planting, CONCAT(id_product,'_', weeks) AS identity
              FROM (
                    SELECT sw_sowing.id_product, pr_products.product, sw_sowing.type, YEARWEEK(:dates,3) AS weeks, SUM(sw_sowing.quantity) AS plant_sowing,
                           SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates)), :dates), sw_sowing.date)/7)>=sw_sowing.weeks_prod, sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS plant_production,
                           ((SUM(sw_sowing.quantity))/pr_products.plant_m2) AS area_planting
                    FROM (
                          SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                          FROM sw_sowing
                          WHERE status != 0
                          AND id_tenant = :id_tenant
                          AND date <= :dates
                          AND multiply != 1
                          AND id_product = 1
                          GROUP BY id_production_unit_detail
                    ) AS sw
                    INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
                    INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
                    INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety
                    WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
                    GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_product, sw_sowing.type
                    HAVING type NOT IN('ER','PR')
              ) AS s";

$statement    = $this->db->prepare($sql);

//get the sunday dates between two dates and bind the variables
for ($i = $dateInitial; $i <= $dateFinal ; $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) {
        if (date('N', $i) == 7){
          $values = [
            ':dates'      => date("Y-m-d", $i),
            ':id_tenant'  => 1
          ];

          $types = [
            ':dates'      => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':id_tenant'  => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
          ];

          $result   = $this->db->executePrepared($statement, $values, $types);
          $final[]  = $result->fetchAll(Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
      }
      return $final;
```

But despite this it is not so fast. The query lasts 5 seconds and I would like it to be faster.

I have also indexed the tables. I would like some opinion on how to best optimize this query or if the way I am doing the query is not adequate.

This is a question that I did before about why I use `GROUP BY` and `MAX(id)`

[get max ids by group mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209300/get-max-ids-by-group-mysql)

Comment: Have you considered using your minimum and maximum date for a single query? you could then group by date and do it with one query. this query running multiple times will get slower the longer the loop. (n+1)

Comment: @MHewison yes, I understand but in this case I need to do in this way, for that reason I have to do a for loop

Comment: Sundays between dates isn't really a task for a database.

Comment: To make the php side better you can also find the first sunday from  the start day and then +7 days through it. It will by maybe faster in larger scales

Comment: `AND date <= :dates` means you're pulling the same dates that you just pulled in the last iteration plus 7 new days.  You probably want to constrain the query to a start and end date instead of all dates up and until :dates.  An index on that field (if possible) will usually help.

Comment: You do `GROUP BY id_production_unit_detail`, but don't mention that column in the `SELECT`.  This seems strange.  Why are you doing that.

Comment: @RickJames yes this is a question that I did before. In this question I explained why I need to group by `id_production_unit_detail` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209300/get-max-ids-by-group-mysql

Comment: Questions about preformance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` for every table involved in the question/query and a `EXPLAIN <query>` output... Without that infromation there is not really much which we can do except gambling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to optiomize it that you create a procedure which:

1. Takes the start and end date as parameter
2. Loops through the dates to find Sundays and put them into a temp table
3. Use the temp table to join with your query and return all the at once

This way you can execute the actual query once instead of 52 times. Should be considerably faster.

The other thing you need to check is your inner query's `GROUP BY` clause. The query returns just `MAX(id)` so the `GROUP BY` is not needed.

Sample usage of temporary table:

```
create procedure sp_sample( in_start date, in_end date)
begin

declare v_date date;

SELECT in_start + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(in_start) day into v_date;

drop temporary table if exists sundays_tmp;
create temporary table sundays_tmp (
d date
);

while (v_date<in_end) do
  insert into sundays_tmp values (v_date);

  select v_date + INTERVAL 7 day into v_date;
end while;

-- Your query here

end
```

Comment: Thanks for you, but Could you provide me an example with temp table please? more o less I understand what you say

Comment: this is an example why I have to use MAX(id) and GROUP BY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209300/get-max-ids-by-group-mysql

Comment: You have the `GROUP BY` over `id_production_unit_detail` meaning you will get `max(id)` for each `id_production_unit_detail`. Yet the main query does not have the reference to `id_production_unit_detail` so it is hard to see why this would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
FLOOR((TO_DAYS(`date` - 737080)/7)
```

Will give you a "week number" that you can use for `GROUP BY`.  Using that should let you get all the results in one pass, not needing an application loop with `SELECT` inside it.

I don't understand the significance of `MAX(id)`, so I can't address the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need the MAX(id) because this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209300/get-max-ids-by-group-mysql